# Can Baton Passed stats be chained from one Pokemon, to another, and so on?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Im working on a little strategy to make my Mega Gallade a tank and Baton Pass plays a huge role in it. But I was wondering, if I use Baton Pass with one Pokemon to a second Pokemon and the second Pokemon uses Baton Pass, will every stat increase still be passed on?

For example, I send out Blaziken first and use Protect which guarantees one Speed Boost. I then use Bulk Up and take a hit, and Speed Boost comes again.

With +2 speed, I baton pass to Togekiss, which ends up with the +1 Attack, +1 Defense and +2 Speed.

I use Agility and get another +2 Speed, making it +4. I then take a hit, but then Baton Pass to Gallade. Would Gallade still have the +1 Attack ,+1 Defense and +2 Speed from the Blaziken?

And say I use Togekiss's Baton Pass AGAIN and pass it to Umbreon first, which uses Swords Dance/Agility and Baton Passes to Gallade. Would the chain of stat increases continue? I'm sorry if I'm being stupid and there's an obvious answer to this.

Comment: Welkcome (back) to Arqade! :) On a side note: you should sign up for an actual account (or continue to use one of the ones you've got), instead of creating them anew each time. This will allow you to earn reputation points and in doing so, unlock new privileges, such as posting pictures, voting on questions, commenting on questions/answers and more. Check out the [Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) page for more info :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Baton Passed stats can be 'chained' onto second, third and even fourth Pokemon (and so on) indefinitely. This is one of the benefits of the Baton Pass and is one viable strategy to set up a Pokemon to sweep 6-0.

Be careful however, the strategy is easy to counter, I wouldn't dedicate an ENTIRE team to a Baton-Pass chain. Make sure you have a backup strategy in mind in case you get disrupted in your chain.

One final thing with your example strategy: After Bulk Up on Blaziken, instead of Baton passing straight away you should Protect again, for a THIRD Speed Boost. Then follow the chain as per normal. This will lead your Togekiss to have +1 Atk, +1 Def and +3 Speed.

Comment: If you battle with Smogon rules this has been nerfed, if I remember well you can have only 3 (or even 1) baton passers per team now.